# MYSQL Indexes when looking up on alternating sets of columns

Tags: mysql, database-design, index

I have a table that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE `connections` (
`connection_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`service_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`parent_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`child_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`connection_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `primary_child` (`parent_id`,`child_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `child_primary` (`child_id`,`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need to do lookups on child_id and get information about parent_id and vice versa.

Ie:

```
SELECT COUNT(`parent_id`) FROM `connections` WHERE `child_id` = 'x'
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(`child_id`) FORM `connections` WHERE `parent_id` = 'x'
```

And some more advanced queries like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `parent_id`
FROM `connections` `c1`
INNER JOIN `connections` `c2`
ON `c1`.`parent_id` = `c2`.`parent_id`
WHERE `c1`.`child_id` = 'x'
AND `c2`.`child_id` = 'y'
```

I'm looking to get a better idea of the most efficient index structure to get quick responses from all the above query examples.

It should be noted that the child/parent pairs will be unique.

EDIT: This table currently holds 40M rows, likely to be much larger in the near future.

Thanks,

Comment: The 2 composite indexes you already have are sufficient for the queries you mention. And I think the `DISTINCT` is not needed in the 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

You already have indices on both colums with the unique constraint. No need for new ones.

I hope you have a good reason avoiding a foreign key. I hope you pay attention to keep your data consistent...

btw: parent_id in your join query is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

1. since `primary_child (parent_id,child_id)` is defined to be unique, then `KEY child_primary (child_id,parent_id)` IS unique, so you only have to define it as `KEY`, not `UNIQUE KEY`. [This is more helpful while inserting though]
2. Having lots of `NULL` values is not recommended. It is not good for performance. If possible, add `NOT NULL` instead. However, this is highly dependent on your requirements. If there are lots of (parent_id, child_id) = (NULL, NULL), then create a new table with these two fields only, and link it to this table.